# GRUB shows Windows recovery instead of normal Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lenovo

I just installed Windows 10 + Ubuntu on my Lenovo laptop. Windows is installed on SSD and Ubuntu is installed on HDD. sda1 is Windows recovery and sda2 is Windows 10. Ubuntu is installed on sdb. Bootloader was installed in sda.

My problem is that GRUB2 shows only win recovery on sda1. I already tried updating grub and running os-prober as was suggested in other asks (where Windows was not found at all), but it only finds sda1. I read somewhere that it may be Lenovo's fault, but I'm not sure about it.

Can I fix it any other way than manually adding Windows 10 to grub files? Various threads says that for Windows 8.1 and 10 that can be buggy to add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong if Windows boots correctly when you select the Windows Recovery entry. GRUB detects all boot loaders and the first Windows boot loader detected is the one that points to the Windows Recovery Environment. The complete Windows Boot Environment starts when you select the Windows Recovery Environment entry from the GRUB boot menu entries list.
So this is absolutely nothing you should worry about ... it is just a misleading wrong name.

Answer (score 0):

In my system (Ubuntu 21.04), the program [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) worked fine.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```